# Need to limit the rows this query is averaging - using postgres AVG

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, average, date-arithmetic

Need help / What I'd like to do is limit the amount of rows this query takes its average from.  I had tried to limit the rows but realized that the query only returns 1 row , the average so limiting did nothing.  Ideally I'd like to return the 10 most recent "handled_at" times and average just those.

```
SELECT
  avg(
    (
      (
        DATE_PART(
          'day',
          handled_at :: TIMESTAMP - created_at :: timestamp
        ) * 24 + DATE_PART(
          'hour',
          handled_at :: TIMESTAMP - created_at :: timestamp
        )
      ) * 60 + DATE_PART(
        'minute',
        handled_at :: TIMESTAMP - created_at :: timestamp
      )
    ) * 60 + DATE_PART(
      'second',
      handled_at :: TIMESTAMP - created_at :: timestamp
    )
  ) / 60
FROM
  registrations
WHERE
  state = 'admitted'
  AND registration_queue_id = 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select avg(extract(epoch from handled_at - created_at)) avg_diff_seconds
from (
    select *
    from registrations
    order by handled_at desc
    limit 10
) r
```

Basically this selects the 10 latest rows, as defined by `handled_at`, and then average the difference between `handled_at` and `created_at` on these rows.

Note that I simplified the date arithmetics: no need for multiple `date_parts()`, this just computes the results in seconds.

I also removed the `timestamp` casting; this is not necessary, unless you are storing your values in string format (which is bad!). You can put it back if that's really needed for some reason.

Comment: This is pretty great .   I tried to do some math to change to minutes and round to the nearest 5.   On my old formula that looked like this:

SELECT round(avg((((DATE_PART('day', handled_at::TIMESTAMP - created_at::timestamp) * 24 + 
                DATE_PART('hour', handled_at::TIMESTAMP - created_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('minute', handled_at::TIMESTAMP - created_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('second', handled_at::TIMESTAMP - created_at::timestamp))/60)/5)*5 FROM registrations WHERE state = 'admitted' AND registration_queue_id=36